# How to secure Laravel project code on client system?

Tags: php, laravel, security, iis

I have to install the Laravel project client local system, then how I can protect the project from copying, deleting, updating... etc?

I'm using IIS to installing the project, is there any option is IIS?

Comment: in my opinion in iis, there is not any kind of option in iis. but you could use some iis features like authentication, authorization and allow access to only specific users and groups. use jquery to disable right click `$(document).ready(function()
{ 
       $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
              return false;
       }); 
})` so no one can copy your code.use https secure bindidng.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal What if they copy the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different obfuscation systems. When you [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) the code, after that code will not be readable so the illegal users will not understand how to modify that code and the coping with make no sense. You can look to that services: [send guard](https://www.zend.com/products/zend-guard), [ion cube](https://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php) etc.